# Django Apache Hello World

Tags: django, apache, deployment, installation

Is there a Hello World tutorial for getting a minimal Django project working with Apache?

*Alternatively*, can anybody tell me where I've gone astray.  I've gone through the [Django tutorials](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/) and everything seems to work as expected, but they don't cover how to actually deploy the example with an apache server.  I found their documentation about how to get [Django working with Apache](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/modwsgi/), but I didn't have any luck with it.  I'm on Ubuntu.  I did `apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`, and then followed the instructions on the second link above.

My /etc/apache2/httpd.conf is a one-liner (is that normal?)

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/john/programming/djangotutorial1/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

And I created a new file at /home/john/programming/djangotutorial1/mysite/apache/django.wsgi that looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/john/programming/djangotutorial1'
if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

And mysite the Django tutorial website which is already populated.

When of go to mywebsite.com I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're getting a 500 error, that means your site is at least loading.  What you should do is enable Debugging in your settings.py and then restart Apache.  Instead of giving you a 500 error, it'll show you what the real error is.

Enabling debugging isn't usually recommended, but since it's just a Hello World, it'll be fine.  But in a production environment you can look through Apache's error logs to find the issue.

Comment: Hmm... that sounded hopeful, but settings.py has DEBUG = True

Comment: `/var/log/apache/error.log` on Ubuntu I believe.  I don't use Ubuntu, but it's definitely in `/var/log/`.

Comment: And it works! Reading the error log pointed it out immediately, but then it took a little more time to get things working again.  Basically, I had left the tutorial in an invalid state from having done a half-way job of following along.

Comment: FYI If you are using wsgi then many initial errors, like syntax errors,  never get displayed in Django whatever your debug settings,  and you have to view in the apache logs.